# Middleware to use multiple implementations in Per-request dependencies

Tags: asp.net-core-middleware

I'm building a middleware for ASP .NET Core 2.1, that would extract some information from the context and inject it into an IService.
Currently there are several services (Profile, Users), all implementing the IService interface.

However, when post-ing to a Profile service, the other Users service is being injected in the middleware.
In the Profile controller, however, the correct service is injected, so it doesn't seem to be a DI problem.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IService theService)
{
    UserInfo serInfo = await GetUserInfoAsync(context).ConfigureAwait(false);

    theService.UserInfo = userInfo; 
}
```

According to Microsoft, [this should be possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#per-request-dependencies).

Any ideas why this is not working?